# Is possible create a Microblogging Service in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

Is possible create a simple Microblogging Service in HTML and CSS with Login similar to Hatena Haiku?

PS: is possible to host in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possibile.

HTML and CSS are used for the appearance of a website. If you want a dynamic website, where users can submit things (like a microblogging service), you'll have to use a language like PHP (which is a server-side language, so cannot be used on Google Drive).

Comment: But if you use Editey?